# Linq to Sql Distinct is returning multiple rows

Tags: t-sql, linq-to-sql

How can I produce something like this with Linq? I'm trying to work something out, this is related to my other post, but my distinct keeps coming back with more rows than expected

[Add Conditional Join Dynamically with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533629/add-conditional-join-dynamically-with-linq)

```
select distinct c.CompanyID, c.CompanyName from Company c
left join CompanyIndustry ci
on c.companyid = ci.companyid
left join CompanyService cs
on c.CompanyID = cs.CompanyID
where cs.ServiceID = 6 and ci.IndustryID = 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use GROUP BY Not distinct

Answer (score 2):

If your companyID has more than one related industry or service, you'll get more than one row per company.